# Showing Invalid Credentials - Reverse geocoding API

Tags: here-api

When trying to access reverse geocoding API using my app ID and code it shows invalid credentials. I have checked and my credentials are all right.
It's working fine before but happened all of a sudden.

```
Type=permission error
Sub type=InvalidCredentials
```

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Please provide us the HTTP Status Code and the exact api query you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `https` instead of `http` in your request as below-

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=Pariser+1+Berl&beginHighlight=<b>&apiKey=apikey
```